# Convert String to Date Java

Tags: java, date, parsing

How can i convert these two strings each one to a respective Date in java?

```
String day = "2021-05-9"  -> Date ?

String hour = "23:59:00"  -> Date ?
```

Comment: Hi @AndreProenza - have a look at this answer to a previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/15310387.   If you still have issues, then please update the question with what you've tried that isn't working ...  ALSO have a think about the hour case - is that TODAY 23:59 or some other date ...??

Comment: How can a date have zero for either month or day-of-month?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: What did your search bring up? How did it fall short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse as the appropriate *java.time* type.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2021-05-23" ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "23:00:00" ) ;
```

If by `Date` you meant `java.util.Date`, that terrible class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Date`.

Also, the `java.util.Date` class represents a moment as seen in UTC. If combining your date and time, we would still be lacking the context of an offset-from-UTC or time zone.

If you want to combine your date and time, use `LocalDateTime` class.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

But be aware that this class cannot represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline, as it does not have an offset or time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
try {
     String day = "2021-05-09";
     String hour = "23:59:00";
     Date dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(day + " " + hour);
     System.out.println(dt);
    }catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.